# [S1000][unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'my-custom-asterisk-username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk

I want to enable CDR-stats to use them with Freepbx on Ubuntu 12.04. I am not able to configure it.

I was fallowing this guide [guide](http://wwww.powerpbx.org/content/asterisk-freepbx-install-guide-ubuntu-v12-asterisk-v11-freepbx-v211).

Everything was fine until

> isql -v MySQL-asteriskcdrdb my-custom-asterisk-username my-custom-asterisk-password

and I get this error:

> [S1000][unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'my-custom-asterisk-username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

I might doing something wrong but I am not able to solve it with this solution:

[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/592125/access-denied-for-user-administratorlocalhost-using-password-yes/)

Answer (score 0):

1) check mysql is running

2) check settings you use in odbc

3) check odbc conenction using

```
   isql connectionname
```

4) if all above working ok, check in asterisk that you put connection info correctly.

optionaly you can enable debug in asterisk.